# FCM Push-уведомления. Отображается базовая иконка на android 8.0

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, fcm

Я использую FCM-консоль для отправки уведомлений на мобильные устройства под управлением Android. Когда приходит уведомление, на живых устройства с 5.0 - 5.1 отображается указанная мной иконка. На симуляторах 5.0 - 8.1 также отображается моя иконка, но на Samsung Galaxy S8 с 8.0 дройдом отображается базовая иконка с роботом в зеленом круге.

Я в основном работаю с iOS и может не знаю каких то тонкостей работы с зеленым роботом, но вроде учел все рекомендации Firebase.
Прописал иконку в билдере и манифесте, сделал ее с альфа-каналом, но не могу понять почему на живом дройде с 8.0 дройдом отображается базовая иконка, которую я удалил из проекта.

Вот код билдера уведомления из FirebaseMessagingService

```js
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pushicon);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoadingScreen.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
        
        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"all")
                .setContentTitle(data.get("title"))
                .setContentText(data.get("text"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                //.setContentInfo("ANY")
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
               // .setColor(Color.GREEN)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pushicon);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

И вот фрагмент манифеста с подключением служб и установкой картинки.

```html
   <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/pushicon" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/pushback"/>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.Firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.Firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
         </service>
```

В defaultConfig прописаны такие версии SDK
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 27

Вот результат на Samsung Galaxy S8 на 8.0 дройде.
[image: Иконка уведомления в статус-баре и шторке]

И то, что я вижу на живых устройствах с 5.0 - 5.1 роботами и всех симуляторах с 5.0-8.1.
[image: Нормальное поведение]

Может я что то не учел?

Comment: судя по скрину, это RoundIcon, прописанная в манифесте и добавленная в  `drawable`. На 8ке используется она (включая и для иконки приложения). Попробуйте удалить `roundIcon` из манифеста.

Comment: В скриншоте, где все нормально тоже 8.0 дройд, но на симуляторе. И круглая иконка переопределена в манифесте. И эта стандартная с роботом удалена из проекта. Иконки я в мипах пробивал на разные разрешения. Говорят, что есть еще пара прог у владельца этого s8 с дефолтной картинкой в пушах. Что то я уже запутался. Странная ситуация.

Comment: Если они у Вас в `mipmap`, тогда почему `android:resource="@` **drawable** `/pushicon"`?

Comment: @woesss Иконки приложения в mipmap. В метах выбрать ресурс студия дает только из drawable. Иконка для пушей используется другая, ведь там нужна с альфой.

Вот кусок из манифеста по иконкам приложения. Если убрать "android:roundIcon", на оболочках системы с круглыми иконками будет отображаться просто белый фон, т.к. дефолтная удалена из проекта.
android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round"

Может дело в "notification channels"? "From Android 8.0 FCM provides a default notification channel with basic settings". Попробую канал сменить...

Comment: Поставил в манифест мету с базовым идентификатором канала. Не прокатило. На S8 все-равно иконка дефолтная (но в симуляторе отображается как надо), даже если в пуше указывать канал.

Comment: UPDT: mipmap можно было брать и не из drawable. Попробую перекинуть иконку в мипы.